# Power BI Calculated measure to count three specific values from a column

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis

I have a table with 500 rows and one of the columns contains a few different values. I want to return a measure that counts the total number of three of the values. 
So for example, in the pic below, I want to calculate the number of times Ages 11, 12 and 13 appears in the table - which is 7 times. 
What is the DAX language for this? 
Thank you

https://i.stack.imgur.com/50ci5.png

Answer (score 0):

The 'IN' function will do this pretty cleanly.  It will let you build a filter that limits your table to the rows whose values match the ones in a list that you supply.  Then just count them up.

```
CountSpecificAges = CALCULATE(
        COUNT (Table1[Age])
        ,  Table1[Age] IN {11, 12, 13}
    )
```